# Удаление элементов стека

Tags: c++, стек

Создать проект, демонстрирующий работу со стеком, организованным на основе списка. Все операции со стеком реализовать через функции. **Разработать функцию удаления элементов стека, кратных 3, если такие есть.** Дополнить проект функцией очистки стека clear(), сохранения в файл и считывания из файла.
Проблема, собственно, в удалении, вроде как удаляет, но при проверке выводом получается совсем не то и выводит ошибку.[image: ошибка] Косяк явно в функции, но решить не получается. Буду очень признательна за помощь

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
struct STACK {
    int Name;
    STACK *next, *prev, *head;
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int buff[100];
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    STACK* Nstk = NULL;
    int n, chislo, i;
    cout << "Сколько чисел необходимо ввести?" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите число" << endl;
        cin >> chislo;
        buff[i] = chislo;
        push(chislo, Nstk);
    }
        delete3(Nstk);
        return 0;
}

 void delete3(STACK *&Nstk)
{
    STACK *temp = Nstk;
    STACK *tmp;
    while (temp)                                           //сама функция удаления//
    {
        if ((temp->Name)%3==0)
        {
            tmp = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << "\nЛишние значения удалены!" << endl;
    cout << "____________" << endl;
}
void push(int strN, STACK *&Nstk)
{
    STACK *tmp = new STACK;//выделение памяти для нового элемента
    tmp->Name = strN;//запись элемента в поле
    tmp->next = Nstk;
    Nstk = tmp;
}
```

Comment: `push(chislo, Nstk);` - ??

Comment: Стирайте все лишнее, оставляйте MCVE (минимальный компилируемый верифицируемый пример).

Comment: @Igor, поместить введённое число в стек Nstk

Comment: @CaptainLeonardo Про это я догадался :). Код добавьте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте смотреть.

1. ```
   struct STACK {
     int Name;
     STACK *next, *prev, *head;
   };
   ```

   зачем здесь поля `prev` и `head`?
2. `buff[i] = chislo;` В чем смысл этой строки?
3. ```
   void delete3(STACK *&Nstk)
   {
     STACK *temp = Nstk;
     STACK *tmp;
     while (temp)   //сама функция удаления//
     {
       if ((temp->Name) %3 == 0)
       {
           tmp = temp;
           temp = temp->next;
           delete tmp;
       }
       temp = temp->next;
     }
     cout << "\nЛишние значения удалены!" << endl;
     cout << "____________" << endl;
   }
   ```

   здесь неправильно почти все

   1. Если мы удалили элемент из вершины стека, то в основной программе указатель на вершину ведет в никуда
   2. Когда мы удаляем элемент, то мы дважды вызываем `temp = temp->next;`

Как должно быть

```
void delete3(STACK *&Nstk) {
  while (Nstk) {
    if ((Nstk->Name) % 3 == 0) {
      STACK *temp = Nstk;
      Nstk = Nstk->next;
      delete temp;
    } else
      Nstk = Nstk->next;
  }
  cout << "\nЛишние значения удалены!" << endl;
  cout << "____________" << endl;
}
```

4. И не забудьте в конце удалить **все** элементы из стека